# ng-bootstrap dropdown not working in Firefox with angular 5?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am using `ng-bootstrap 1.0.1` in my angular project. It is working well in `chrome (latest version).` but in `firefox (latest version)`, It is throwing error `too much recursion`, When click dropdown button.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
       <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
         <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

After upgrading my ng-bootstrap package 1.0.0 to 2.0.0.I got below error,

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Are you using any kind of `javascript` or `jquery` function with this dropdown?

Comment: Thanks for reply.No i am not use any scripting functions in component.i assured that error is comes from html file

Comment: No normally `too much recursion` error occur from `javascript` or 'jquery'. and especially it will shown in `firefox`.

Comment: ya exactly.i removed all scripts then run project it shows same error.  i think it is package or package version error.

Comment: If you are using `angular 5`, use ng-boostrap `2.x.x` version. use this command : `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Comment: Thanks i tried ng-bootstrap updated version of 2.0.0. but error not cleared.

Comment: i got another error also after upgrade ng-bootstrap package i.e this._anchor is undefined.

Comment: try to remove `this._anchor is undefined` error. If this error will solve than your above error will automatically solve.

Comment: I updated my question.Please review it once.It is not my scripting error.

Comment: Maybe this is also `ng-bootstrap` version error. try to use latest version. In the latest version working fine. Check this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ja3qga

Comment: i can't upgrade ng-bootstrap package after 2.0.0 because it is only support angular 6.

Comment: Okk than use @2.2.2 version

Comment: Above 2.0.0 version it is not supported angular 5. i got error so i downgrade 2.0.0.In that example you are using angular 6.